# How do I loop over result rows and return calculated values?

Tags: views

I cannot get proper results from View PHP field.

I've set up a Flipped Table view of entity form submission of which I'm trying to calculate "results" (sum and count(for avg)) with following code

```
$results = array(); // For results
$static = get_object_vars($row);
dsm($static);
foreach($static as $key => $value) {
    if(strpos($key,'field_') !== FALSE){
        if($value !== NULL){
            $results[$static['entityform_id']]['count']++; // Count no. of fields
            $results[$static['entityform_id']]['sum']= $results[$static['entityform_id']]['sum']+$value; // Count sum of field values
        }
    }
}
return json_encode($results[$static['entityform_id']]);
```

which results:

```
{"count":55,"sum":55}   {"count":55,"sum":110}  {"count":55,"sum":165}  {"count":55,"sum":220}
```

At this point I do not understand that why sum is always row index * sum? Eg.1 =55, 2=110, 3=165... All the submissions have the same fields and field values (clones) which explaines sums but I can't figure out that where this multiplication "logic" happens?

It seems like it is looping/counting all four result rows every time.

Answer (score 0):

This is because $results[$static['entityform_id']]['sum'] already contains the sum result from previous loop result.
Thus it adds 55 for every row iteration.
Try adding the current array index to $results inside foreach loop.

Comment: How can it contain since entityform_id is different(1...4) and being used as an array index to separate calculated values for each submission? It should create new index and therefore value should be empty. But I'll try to use some other method for indexes and we'll see what then happens...

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong..
How can entity form id be different if you are iterating over the submissions of a particular form..

Comment: Yeah, I know. That's a bit misleading. In Views guidelines it is named like that as "entityform id" but the description states that it is actually submission ID. And I did verify it by debugging.

Comment: Okay, now that I tried to debug the actual field values it shows that all values are overriden. For the first submission value is 1 and so on until 4 (submission id). And to get these results I'm only using print function to view $row variable and not modifying any variable. Really weird...

Comment: Did you try creating views handlers for your entity fields ??

That way you can get more flexibility with operations and customizations on the fields.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea about Views API or related handlers. Can I use it to create a field "instance" as part of each result row? By a quick review it seems like "adding new field to query" which is pointing into already available field entities. However, in my solution I need so to speak JIT or on-the-fly field that is calculated from available fields.